# How to make it "type it in." Right now, it just pastes my text into the text box

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

This is the code I am using. This is basic selenium stuff. But the issue is the send_keys method. Instead of typing into the textbox like a human, it just pastes in the text. I would like it to enter text into the text box as a human would type it. This is one of my first questions so sorry if I don't have the right formatting.

```
try:
    first_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "firstName"))
    )
    last_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lastName"))
    )
    username= WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
    )
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "Passwd"))
    )
    confirm_password = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "ConfirmPasswd"))
    )
    next_1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc qIypjc TrZEUc lw1w4b']"))
    )
except:
    driver.quit()

first_name.send_keys('Jeff')
last_name.send_keys('McMemes')
username.send_keys('Thisisjustatestcase1')
password.send_keys('omglukesucks123')
confirm_password.send_keys('omglukesucks123')
next_1.click()
```

Comment: `presence_of_*` means that the element exists in the DOM, not that it's accessible. If you are going to interact with the element you should use `element_to_be_clickable` when you plan to click the element otherwise use `visibility_of_element_located`. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: Also, you likely don't need to wait for each of those elements on the page since they are likely all on the same form. Waiting for the first one will probably be sufficient. If it's ready, the rest will likely be ready also.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it send each character after a short delay in a loop.

```py
import time
for character in "Jeff":
    first_name.send_keys(character)
    time.sleep(0.2) # typing delay
```

and so on for the rest of the elements.